# Possible for discord bot to reply to message that the message calling the bot replied too?

Tags: python, discord.py

Sorry, this is hard to explain, but I'm curious if there is a way for a bot to reply to the message the bot call is replying to. So let's say somebody is asking a question, and I have a Q&A bot but the person asking the question forgets to call the bot. How can I make it so that I can reply to their question with the bot call and question but have the bot reply to the same message I'm replying to with the answer (not reply to me who called the bot)

I hope this makes sense lol. If confused on the question, maybe this will clarify.

**Person A asks questions (message 1)**

**Person B reply's to message 1 and calls the bot and asks the bot a question (message 2)**

**Bot replies to message 1 with the answer to the question that person B asked in message 2.**

Is something like this possible in python discord.py? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wanting to reply to the replied message right? if yes then you can achieve this using `message.reference`. The code below will reply to the replied message

```py
@bot.command()
async def reply(ctx, arg):
    reference = ctx.message.reference
    if reference is None:
        return await ctx.reply("You did not reply to any message")
    await reference.resolved.reply(arg)
```

This first gets the referenced (replied) message, then checks if it is none (in case there is no reply) and if it is none then sends a message and stops the function, otherwise if there is a replied message then it replies to that message using the provided arg instead

An example of what this does:
[image: example]

You also may wanna check for [discord.DeletedReferencedMessage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.DeletedReferencedMessage) in case the replied message gets deleted